# Display desired result by using Group by Mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have a mysql table with some repeated records, there was a column `Error_code`. In that if all data is correct then ok will be insert for all columns. If some data is wrong then Error will be insert for those wrong data records. If there is no Error, ok will be displayed in the related column.

But if Error is there then i want to display Error by using group by. How can I write query for that?

Sample table

```
voucherid ean error_code
123456    234 OK
123456    435 OK
123456    345 Ok
```

I am using below query by using group by

```
select voucherid, error_code 
from voucher_info 
group by voucher id
```

This query will return this data:

```
voucherid error_code
123456     ok
```

But if I have error code in the data the table will look like below

```
voucherid ean error_code
123456    234 OK
123456    435 Error
123456    345 Ok
```

Now I want to display error_code value as Error like below.

```
voucherid error_code
123456     Error
```

How to do that by using group by ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to fetch only data with 'Error' code not OK?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have 2 tables or only one. If you have one table and
wants only to see if there a error you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
    vi.voucherid
    , GROUP_CONCAT(ean) eans
    , IF( COUNT(*) - SUM(IF(error_code = 'ERROR' OR @err = 'ERROR' , 0 , 1)) = 0 , 'OK', 'ERROR') error_code
FROM voucher_info vi
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @err:='') AS initial
GROUP BY voucherid;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> select * from voucher_info;
+-----------+------+------------+
| voucherid | ean  | error_code |
+-----------+------+------------+
|    123456 | 234  | OK         |
|    123456 | 435  | OK         |
|    123456 | 345  | OK         |
|    123457 | 234  | OK         |
|    123457 | 435  | ERROR      |
|    123457 | 345  | OK         |
+-----------+------+------------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->     vi.voucherid
    ->     , GROUP_CONCAT(ean) eans
    ->     , IF( COUNT(*) - SUM(IF(error_code = 'ERROR' OR @err = 'ERROR' , 0 , 1)) = 0 , 'OK', 'ERROR') error_code
    -> FROM voucher_info vi
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @err:='') AS initial
    -> GROUP BY voucherid;
+-----------+-------------+------------+
| voucherid | eans        | error_code |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|    123456 | 234,435,345 | OK         |
|    123457 | 234,435,345 | ERROR      |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0,01 sec)

mysql>
```